# Como apagar os dados de uma tabela em VBA Access

Tags: microsoft-access, vba

Preciso de um comando em [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) para excluir os registros da minha tabela `REPETIRTEL` no momento em que fecho o meu formulário. Esse formulário não tem essa tabela como origem de dados, por isso preciso que o comando chame essa tabela e depois desabilite a mensagem de confirmação de exclusão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro criei uma consulta exclusão da tabela REPETIRTEL com a Query de Delete, depois chamei essa consulta e pronto, ficou assim:

```
 Private Sub Form_Close()
  Application.DoCmd.SetWarnings False
  DoCmd.OpenQuery "deleteREPETIRTEL", acViewNormal
  Application.DoCmd.SetWarnings True
 End Sub
```

Primeiro desabilitei as mensagens do Access
Chamei a Query
Habilitei novamente as mensagens.

Answer (score 0):

Outra alternativa:

```
Private Sub Form_Close()
  Application.DoCmd.SetWarnings False
  Application.DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM REPETIRTEL"
  Application.DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```